# Conditionally set type of input

Tags: angular

In the code below, is there a way to conditionally set the type of an input based on a component property, with something like:

`<input type="typeof(model[key])">` or `[ng-type]="typeof(model[key])"` or `<input type="typeof(model.key)">` or something else along those lines?

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendQuery()">
  <div *ngFor="let key of modelKeys">
      {{key}} 
      <input  #myInput [ng-type]="typeof(model[key])" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" required *ngIf="key==='q'" appNoSpecialChars/>
      <input  #myInput [ng-type]="typeof(model[key])" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" minlength = '2' maxlength='4' *ngIf="key==='stars'" appNoSpecialChars />      
      <input  #myInput [ng-type]="typeof(model[key])" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" *ngIf="key!=='q' && key!=='stars'" appNoSpecialChars/> 
      <p *ngIf="!myForm.form.get(key)?.valid" >Not valid</p> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: you can try `type="{{ typeof(model[key]) }}"`

Comment: I don't think you can use `typeof` inside template expressions, but you can use `[attr.type]` to set an attribute value. You'll have to use a component function to compute the value.

Comment: I don't think that you can bind the `type` property. See the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329).

Comment: @ogTag, thank you for your comments. I tried implementing a component function as follows, but for the numbers fields it gives me `objects` instead of `numbers`. Any ideas as to why and how to fix? 

public inputType = (key : string) : string => {
  console.log(key + ": " + typeof(this.model[key]));
  return typeof(this.model[key]);
}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding to the type attribute, try using a structural directive like `*ngIf` or `[ngSwitch]` to display the correct input. Something like:

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let key of modelKeys">
    {{key}}
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="model[key]">
        <input #myInput *ngSwitchCase="'text'" type="text" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" />
        <input #myInput *ngSwitchCase="'email'" type="email" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" />
        <input #myInput *ngSwitchCase="'password'" type="password" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" />
    </ng-container>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: this is a great approach for the question.